# Outlook is disconnected after the machine is up for 2 days

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, exchange

I'm using outlook 2007 with exchange. the outlook is connected to the company domain but my machine is on another domain we have.

I can't figure why the outlook is disconnected after 2 days, and reconnect back after restart. I'm not IT professional but will be happy to get some help with that.

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely because your authentication ticket with the domain has expired. Whenever you log in a new authentication ticket is generated which is valid for a certain period of time, and in this cause it seems to be 48 Hours.

Because your on a different domain this will only get renewed when you physically log in, whereas if the server and domain was the same, it will get renewed automatically.

Comment: thanks, so if i will log out and in, i wont have to restart the machine?

Comment: Potentially I would suspect that will work.

Comment: thanx for your answer, but can i regenerate the ticket manually without log out and back in?

Comment: No you can't. It is generate when authenticating with the server during login.